# Is there a command to modify an integer range in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Say for example I have a timer process, is there such a command to modify the integer variable range during a modelsim simulation? For example I know there is the "change" command but that only modifies the current integer value not the "range" of the integer. For work purposes I am not allowed to change the values and can only work through modelsim commands to modify values.

```
variable timer : integer range 0 to 500;
```

Comment: Why? it was probably limited in range for a reason.

Comment: For verification purposes we are allowed to use force/change commands to speed up simulation time.

Comment: Using Forces is really only for fault injection. But even so, why would you want to force a value outside the limited range - It is probably limited for a good reason...

Comment: It seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the range using a generic `UPPER_BOUND`, like

```
entity my_tb is
  (generic UPPER_BOUND : natural := 1000)
end entity;
...

variable timer : integer range 0 to UPPER_BOUND;
```

and modify the generic on each simulation run

`vsim -gUPPER_BOUND=500 my_tb`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've suggested to my team last week and this is the solution we are going with.